# How do I write php code to send JSON data from MySQL database to my AngularJS application

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, rest, angularjs

I'm trying to wire up my angularjs application to get JSON data from a database (mySQL), using PHP as the server-side language (a language I taught myself this summer, and am most comfortable with).

Having looked at these links: ([Angular JS: Full example of GET/POST/DELETE/PUT client for a REST/CRUD backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376890/angular-js-full-example-of-get-post-delete-put-client-for-a-rest-crud-backend))  ([How to access the services from RESTful API in my angularjs page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394089/how-to-access-the-services-from-restful-api-in-my-angularjs-page)), I feel very confident in how the AngularJS code should look, but I don't know what the URL is doing in these $resource examples.

I've never implemented a RESTful API in any language, and I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what the code should be inside the  tags.  Explanations on the web are often too technical for my skill level.  I've tried asking my professors, but I haven't found one who has implemented REST before.

I appreciate any time and any help,
Andrew

Comment: That's a very broad question. It's like asking how to create a website. Do you have experience with PHP? Are you already using a PHP framework?

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I read through and created some php projects based on  the O'Riley text 'Building Dynamic Websites  using Php, MySQL, CSS and Javascript', which is a procedural based programming style. I have considered using cakephp or Laravel, but I don't think I'm ready for that layer of abstraction yet.  At any rate I found an example that helped me, and I will post it later for anyone else who might be at the same level as me. I'm on my phone at the moment,  but will share my resource when I'm on my computer.

Comment: Here is the promised link: http://pastebin.com/7RDYfY7W

Comment: You can download some very good documentation on the apigee website as well: http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices

Comment: I appreciate your help, jvandemo.    I've implemented my first ever rest API, and it feels really neat! :)

Comment: Nice to hear. Keep learning, write as much code as you can and just post a question if you need help. Good luck!