# how to integrate springREST into wicket website?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

we maintain online book shop using java wicket and it also have search function for finding books in MYSQL database. If someone search for "Fiction" in the search box, the results will contain metadata of each result. If a user click on title, it will take him/her to details page.

I have a requirement to add functionality of reviews box/form in the details page using spring. we do maintian 2 other websites which needs similar sort of work. So we decided to develope this feature as a small individual and re-usable application then integrate into java Wicket or ZEND framework. 
 what i need to do is:-
1) get details from the form like name, email and review information - JSP or HTML, JQUERY
2) show the entered review on the web page and post those details to MYSQL (update the reviews table in db) when form submitted. springREST

Is it really possible to accomplish using SpringREST? or is there any options for this?
can anyone give some ideas on this requirement how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this. If you implement this new feature with javascript, you can include it to both frameworks. I would suggest you use a javascript framework like AngularJS or Bootstrap as they will make calling the rest service easier.

In addition you need to deploy your rest service as an application or bundle it with your existing application that contains the wicket app.

Here you'll find an example on calling rest service with AngularJS [How to access the services from RESTful API in my angularjs page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394089/how-to-access-the-services-from-restful-api-in-my-angularjs-page)