# How to get values stored in remoteMethod()

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

I wan to retrieve my results that are stored inside the /geoCodes/geocode. I manage to insert values into it but I am unable to get the results to display in my html.

[Strongloop explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTORz.png)

[Console to show results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJRD8.png)

```
        // maplink sample: http://maps.google.com/?q=37.2110625,-121.8054238
        var maplink = "http://maps.google.com/?q=" + lat + "," + lng;
        console.log('maplink is ' + maplink);
        // make a callback function cb
        cb(null,maplink);
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected behavior, and how does actual behavior differs?

Comment: It will get the input and return a maplink which im already able to get but the results is displayed in the console which is not what I want. I want to place the return value(maplink) into my html. @MarcoS

Comment: Will this code run in browser or server-side? You should supply some more 'contour' info... :-)

Comment: This code will run in the server-side. My inputs will be placed in the browser. @MarcoS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a "browser" app to get values form a server, you have to setup a client-server interface. For example implement a RESTful API on your server (see [express site](http://expressjs.com/), and for example this nice [tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/)).
Your server side API will expose some methods (for example `getGeoLocation`), and then, in your client side app (in the browser), it'll be easy to get the values from your service (see for example this [SO question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394089/how-to-access-the-services-from-restful-api-in-my-angularjs-page)).

Comment: I added my value into /geoCodes/geocode and there is only the post method. There is no get method for it. The photo of the explorer is in at the above.

Comment: O.k., so you did setup an API with one POST method, accepting an address and returning a maplink (sorry, I'm quite sleepy, this morning, yet... :-). Perfect. You said you did test in in console and it works. Did you test it with curl, or in the browser?

Comment: Yup, i tried to retrieve the maplink to show in the browser but it doesn't work. How do I display the maplink?

Comment: Please show the url you did put in the browser addres and the results in console. And, please, accept this answer... :-)

Comment: This is the url that i placd in the console: http://localhost:3000/#/find-location. The console displays the exact same thing as the one shown in the picture after I place the inputs.

Comment: O.k. So your API do work remotely too. I would conclude the issue is in client code. Can you show the relevant portion?