# How to POST data from AngularJS to Struts 2 using REST

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, struts2

I need to get the value from client side to server side. I am using AngularJS and Struts2 REST.

My controller doesn't get the value passed or am I wrong in passing or using RESTful controller?

**Here is my code:**

**`angularcontroller.js`:**

```js
app.controller('saveAddCatCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.save = function(newAddCat){
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/additionalcategory",
            data: $scope.additionalCategory.addCatName
        }).success(function(data, status, header, config){
            //success
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config){
            //error
        });
}
});
```

**Here is my REST controller:**

```java
public class AdditionalcategoryController extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<Object>{

private AdditionalCategoryRepository additionalCategoryRepository =
        (AdditionalCategoryRepository)ServletActionContext.getServletContext()
        .getAttribute("additionalCategoryRepository");

private List<AdditionalCategory>            additionalCategories;
public AdditionalCategory                   additionalCategory = new AdditionalCategory();
private int                                 id;

public HttpHeaders index(){
    setAdditionalCategories(additionalCategoryRepository.findAllAdditionalCategory());
    System.out.println("GET api/additionalCategory");
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index").disableCaching();
}

public HttpHeaders create(){
    additionalCategoryRepository.createAdditionalCategory(additionalCategory);
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("create").disableCaching();
}

public void setAdditionalCategories(List<AdditionalCategory> additionalCategories){
    this.additionalCategories = additionalCategories;
}

@Override
public Object getModel() {
    if (additionalCategories == null){
        return additionalCategory;
    }else{
        return additionalCategories;
    }
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public List<AdditionalCategory> getAdditionalCategories() {
    return additionalCategories;
}

public AdditionalCategory getAdditionalCategory() {
    return additionalCategory;
}

public void setAdditionalCategory(AdditionalCategory additionalCategory) {
    this.additionalCategory = additionalCategory;
}

}
```

Comment: you should post you code it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the services from RESTful API in my angularjs page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394089/how-to-access-the-services-from-restful-api-in-my-angularjs-page)

Comment: can that also read struts2 rest? TIA.

Comment: tried it but struts2 controller don't get the data from angular. :(

Comment: Does your struts2 controller respond?

Comment: yes. it responds. It displays logs but always have null pointer exception.

Comment: What is null? What do you post? Your `create` method looks a bit strange.

Comment: the additionalCategory.

Answer (score 0):

Since angular service `http` sends JSON, you can send a JSON object using `data` property. The JSON object will be deserialized to your model class properties because you are using `ModelDriven` or `Action` class properties otherwise.

[Struts2 REST plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/) is made to handle JSON content from the request. It's possible due `ContentTypeInterceptor`, which is called `rest`, be able to find JSON handler for the request. The JSON handler is guessed from the `Content-Type` header or `.json` extension to the file in the URL. You can use either ways, but second is easier.

**Note:**

URLs without a file extension the Struts2 REST plugin defaulting to handle `xhtml` content. So you can modify your code

```js
$http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api/additionalcategory.json",
    data: {}
}).success(function(data, status, header, config){
    //success
}).error(function(data, status, header, config){
    //error
});
```

---