# how to Call restAPI in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

i am new AngularJs, how to debug code in angularjs using Visual Stduio 2013, i am calling RestAPI in angular but data does not show , please help me. please check below code and Images.

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:9000/employees").then(function (response) {
                $scope.myData = response.data;

            });
        });

<!-- language: lang-html -->

      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
            <pre>{{myData | json}}</pre>

            <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

            <ul>
                <!--<li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.Fname }}
                </li>-->
            </ul>


        </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the services from RESTful API in my angularjs page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394089/how-to-access-the-services-from-restful-api-in-my-angularjs-page)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `cross-domain origin policy`. Do run your index.html in a `webserver` and by not just loading it in browser relatively.

If you have python installed, go to your folder where the index.html is present and run the following command.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 3000
```

Then fire up `http://localhost:3000` in your browser, you should not have any issues.

Comment: i don't have python

Comment: @AdeelKhan: use any webserver... it could be xampp or python or node http.server

Comment: i create the webserver but its show same error  Origin 'http://192.168.1.102:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: http://localhost:9000, its in 9000 and you are in 8080... keep both the client/server in same...

Answer (score 0):

Another useful option is to use http-server from one of the npm packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: In your backend, allow CORS request to all, i.e. set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to *